# CosmosDB not using indices under certain circumstances

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I noticed an odd behaviour of CosmosDB regarding the use of indices.

A few words to my setup:
It is a partitioned CosmosDB with 25 partitions.
There are two fields of arrays containing strings which are named *a* and *f*. They have the following indexing policy:

```
{
    "path": "/a/[]/?",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
        },
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "path": "/f/[]/?",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
        },
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
        }
    ]
}
```

There might be the case that a string that is in field *a* for one document occurs in *f* in another document.

The odd behaviour occurs when I execute the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Documents d
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(d.a, 'some-string')
```

If 'some-string' doesn't occur in any others document's *f* field, all paritions have an IndexHitRation of 1 (as seen in QueryMetrics included in response). This is the behaviour I expect.

But if 'some-string' does occur in any others document's *f* field, the partitions containing such a document report an IndexHitRatio of 0 which has a great impact on the used RUs.

Can there be any mistakes in my setup that lead to this behaviour?
Can any one else reproduce this behaviour, so this is a bug?

Comment: Can you please try this with String/Range/-1 for both paths instead of Hash/Range/-1? Do you see the same IndexHitRatio?

Comment: I only changed one path to Range which lead to a IndexHitRatio of 1 for all partitions. This finding lead me to the answer I posted.  
So, thank you for hinting me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of this behaviour I used different precision values for each field. So, now field *a* has precision -1 and field *f* has precision 7.

My conclusion from this would be that they were written to the same index when using the same precision. But this would be some unexpected behaviour of a database?!